# Error when upload files to Azure Blob storage through Django App

Tags: django, azure

I need to build a file manager to upload images from a Django app to Azure blob storage. However, when I try to upload a file to Azure's blob storage, I get the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/marilynmarquez/Desktop/webster/python/file_manager/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "/Users/marilynmarquez/Desktop/webster/python/file_manager/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/marilynmarquez/Desktop/webster/python/file_manager/website/files/views.py", line 27, in upload_file
new_file=upload_file_to_blob(file)
File "/Users/marilynmarquez/Desktop/webster/python/file_manager/website/files/azure_controller.py", line 57, in upload_file_to_blob
blob_client =create_blob_client(file_name = file_name) #problem
File "/Users/marilynmarquez/Desktop/webster/python/file_manager/website/files/azure_controller.py", line 20, in create_blob_client
storage_credentials = secret_client.get_secret(name=settings.AZURE_STORAGE_KEY_NAME) #problem
File "/Users/marilynmarquez/Desktop/webster/python/file_manager/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/core/tracing/decorator.py", line 78, in wrapper_use_tracer
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/marilynmarquez/Desktop/webster/python/file_manager/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/keyvault/secrets/_client.py", line 72, in get_secret
bundle = self._client.get_secret(
File "/Users/marilynmarquez/Desktop/webster/python/file_manager/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/keyvault/secrets/_generated/_operations_mixin.py", line 1574, in get_secret
return mixin_instance.get_secret(vault_base_url, secret_name, secret_version, **kwargs)
File "/Users/marilynmarquez/Desktop/webster/python/file_manager/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/core/tracing/decorator.py", line 78, in wrapper_use_tracer
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/marilynmarquez/Desktop/webster/python/file_manager/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/keyvault/secrets/_generated/v7_3/operations/_key_vault_client_operations.py", line 694, in get_secret
pipeline_response = self._client._pipeline.run(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
File "/Users/marilynmarquez/Desktop/webster/python/file_manager/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/core/pipeline/_base.py", line 211, in run
return first_node.send(pipeline_request)  # type: ignore
File "/Users/marilynmarquez/Desktop/webster/python/file_manager/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/core/pipeline/_base.py", line 71, in send
response = self.next.send(request)
File "/Users/marilynmarquez/Desktop/webster/python/file_manager/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/core/pipeline/_base.py", line 71, in send
response = self.next.send(request)
File "/Users/marilynmarquez/Desktop/webster/python/file_manager/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/core/pipeline/_base.py", line 71, in send
response = self.next.send(request)
[Previous line repeated 2 more times]
File "/Users/marilynmarquez/Desktop/webster/python/file_manager/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/core/pipeline/policies/_redirect.py", line 160, in send
response = self.next.send(request)
File "/Users/marilynmarquez/Desktop/webster/python/file_manager/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/core/pipeline/policies/_retry.py", line 512, in send
raise err
File "/Users/marilynmarquez/Desktop/webster/python/file_manager/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/core/pipeline/policies/_retry.py", line 484, in send
response = self.next.send(request)
File "/Users/marilynmarquez/Desktop/webster/python/file_manager/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/core/pipeline/policies/_authentication.py", line 116, in send
self.on_request(request)
File "/Users/marilynmarquez/Desktop/webster/python/file_manager/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/keyvault/secrets/_shared/challenge_auth_policy.py", line 71, in on_request
_enforce_tls(request)
File "/Users/marilynmarquez/Desktop/webster/python/file_manager/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/keyvault/secrets/_shared/challenge_auth_policy.py", line 41, in _enforce_tls
raise ServiceRequestError(
azure.core.exceptions.ServiceRequestError: Bearer token authentication is not permitted for non-TLS protected (non-https) URLs.
[06/Feb/2023 18:44:58] "POST /upload_file/ HTTP/1.1" 500 155467

This is my azure_controller.py:

```
from io import BytesIO
import uuid
from pathlib import Path

from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.keyvault.secrets import SecretClient
from azure.storage.blob import BlobClient
from django.conf import settings

from . import models

ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = ['.png', '.jpg']

def create_blob_client(file_name):
    default_credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
    secret_client=SecretClient(
        vault_url = settings.AZURE_VAULT_ACCOUNT,
        credential = default_credential
    )
    storage_credentials = secret_client.get_secret(name=settings.AZURE_STORAGE_KEY_NAME)

    return BlobClient(
        account_url = settings.AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT,
        container_name = settings.AZURE_APP_BLOB_NAME,
        blob_name = file_name,
        credential = storage_credentials.value,
    )

def check_file_ext(path):
    ext = Path(path).suffix
    return ext in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS


def download_blob(file):
    blob_client=create_blob_client(file)
    if not blob_client.exists():
        return
    blob_content = blob_client.download_blob()
    return blob_content


def save_file_url_to_db(file_url):
    new_file = models.File.objects.create(file_url = file_url)
    new_file.save()
    return new_file


def upload_file_to_blob(file):
    if not check_file_ext(file.name):
        return

    file_prefix = uuid.uuid4().hex
    ext=Path(file.name).suffix
    file_name = f"{file_prefix}{ext}"
    file_content = file.read()
    file_io = BytesIO(file_content)
    blob_client =create_blob_client(file_name = file_name)
    blob_client.upload_blob(data=file_io)
    file_object=save_file_url_to_db(blob_client.url)

    return file_object
```

This is my settings.py:

```
Django settings for website project.

from pathlib import Path
import environ


BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


env = environ.Env()

environ.Env.read_env() 
 
AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT=env.str('AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT')
AZURE_VAULT_ACCOUNT=env.str('AZURE_VAULT_ACCOUNT')
AZURE_STORAGE_KEY_NAME=env.str('AZURE_STORAGE_KEY_NAME')
AZURE_APP_BLOB_NAME=env.str('AZURE_APP_BLOB_NAME')


SECRET_KEY = env('MY_SECRET')

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []



INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'files',
    'django_extensions',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'website.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'website.wsgi.application'



DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation


AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)


STATIC_URL = 'static/'

# Default primary key field type


DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

Some of the documentation I read advises using a Security Prncipal in Azure, which implies setting up Azure AD, but every time I try to go to Azure AD in my account, I get a  message saying I'm not allowed (I'm the owner of the account). I honestly have no idea where to go from here or how to begin to fix this. Can someone help?

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: The error message says - `Bearer token authentication is not permitted for non-TLS protected (non-https) URLs`. It looks like you are using `http` instead of `https` in your storage account URL. Can you try with `https`? Your account URL should be something like `https://account.blob.core.windows.net`.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Gaurav Mantri, thanks for your reply. I made the URL change (copied from Azure and double-checked for errors), but am still getting the same error.

Comment: Just to clarify: I think the error is being generated by Azure when Localhost tries to connect, because it is NOT an HTTPS server but an HTTP one. I tried using mkcert to create a TSL certificate, and it generated the files, but I'm still getting the errors.